# get database changes from scheduled process reflected live in browser

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp-classic

If possible I would like to get some ideas to get the following done :

I have a single webpage on my website I am working on.
The page is processing information like:

-get a session from webserver (default behaviour)
-make contact with database
-get records and show them on screen
-I can modify the records and changes are reflected in database

lets say table alpha with columns:

```
ColumName   TinyINt
column1     0
column2     1
column3     0
column4     1
column5     2
```

now I have a scheduled process modifying the records and completing the processes
and marking them with 3 which means complete.

Complete is when a task has been completed and the end value for each column has changed to:

```
column1     3
column2     3
column3     3
column4     3
column5     3
```

How could I get close to or achieve that I see the columns live being changed on my webpage
while the scheduled process is modifying them for lets say at least 1-2 minutes.

I could accomplish this by polling the database but perhaps there is another way.

Available toolset is classic asp,jquery,sql server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some type of polling/refresh is the only way.

The server holds the database and will not automatically send input to the user until it is requested, at which time the server processes can collect the new information and send a response back to the user.